# sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash does not work while installing Ubuntu Touch, package cannot be located

Tags: package-management

When I enter this command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash`, my terminal shows this problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-device-flash
```

What should I do now, I want to install Ubuntu Touch on my phone.

Or can anyone tell me another way of installing Ubuntu Touch other official website?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use? The package you mention is available only for [trusty - 14.04 LTS and xenial - 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-device-flash).

Comment: I am not sure Ubuntu touch for phone is still in development by Ubuntu (UBports has it now, see: https://ubports.com/), and that error simply means that package is not in a repo meant for your version

Answer (score 3):

https://ubports.com/ubuntu-touch/get-ut

Ubuntu phone is supported by ubports nowdays, checkout above link.